# How to check if angular spinner is active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spinner

I am working on angularJS web application. I have a modal popup on which I show spinner while loading screen. Now there is need to **identify if spinner is active** (by using it's name) in html template. Can anybody please let me know how can achieve this in angular. I google for answer but no success yet.

Please help..!!

Answer (score 0):

How you are showing the spinner, must be a image inside a div and setting it's display to block i suppose.

so you can use `ng-show="isLoading"`

and set `$scope.isLoading = true` when you open the pop-up and so this will make the spinner display and inside your service ( http) call on success handler you can reset it to - `$scope.isLoading = false` so that it hides the spinner.

is that what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic logic:

In your controller initialize a `$scope` variable as so:

```
$scope.showSpinner = false;
```

Then inside the relevant js function, that executes on  modal open, run this:

```
$scope.showSpinner = true;
```

You should also have a spinner in your view html which displays the spinner when rendered, for example:

```
<div id="spinner" ng-if="showSpinner">    </div>
```

If you need more info please post your code..